# How can I connect components via angular event bindings?

Tags: angular, events, binding, onclick, event-binding

I want to configure a component that performs a survey, and when a button is clicked in the main component, the survey component window opens by the click event. How can I connect the two?

As far as I know, only functions can be used after the (click) event, is there any way to connect a component there??

<button (cilck)="*I want to put a component here*">

If there is another way, please tell me.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use 3rd library [Ng-boostrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) to open survey modal.

Comment: You can use Subject for event communication between both components! maybe this link helps you : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject